# jQuery click does not fire consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I have an issue regarding the jQuery click event. The first time the page get loaded it does not work. After a refresh it works fine. I assume it has to do with the browser caching the files somehow.

This is the code:

```
$(window).ready(
    function() {

        $("#language-input").click(function() {
            $("#language-dropdown").show();
        });
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you using `$(window).ready` instead of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: No particular reason.$(document).ready might be a better idea.

Comment: `$(window).ready` will be executed after all the external resources are fully loaded, images, iframe content etc. Some of these might be cached, and the loading happens faster when refreshing. `$(document).ready` executes immediately after all the HTML has been parsed, it doesn't wait images or iframes to be fully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, which was mentioned in one of the comments, was to use:

```
$(document).on("click", "#element", function()
```

This seemed to work for dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`$("#language-input").click(function() {`

You can use

`$("#language-input").on('click', function() {`.

This will ensure that the `click` event is fired even if the element is loaded dynamically.

You final code would be without `$(window).ready(function() {` :

```
$("#language-input").on('click', function() {
    $("#language-dropdown").show();
});
```

Comment: That's not how event delegation works.  `$("x").click(` is **just shorthand for** `$("x").on("click", `   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Well, if the element is loaded dynamically than `click` won't work. You need to use `on` for it. And this would ensure that an event is clicked every-time whenever user clicks it.

Comment: I agree that if the element is loaded dynamically then `click` won't work, but *neither will* `$("element").on("click"` as they are the same.   You're looking for `$(document).on("click", "#element", function() ...`

Comment: I believe both should work, though not sure. Let me add your suggestion too in the answer and wait for the OP to check or share more details. What say?